# Can't type into TinyMCE editor when rendered form from ajax reponse

Tags: ajax, tinymce

calling a form via ajax and I am using a tinymce editor. When the form has loaded I can't type in the editor. 
When I set a 1 second delay it will work, but the page is jumping to the bottom.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

With the information you provided a possible solution is to initialize the tincymce editor after you have loaded the form with ajax.

Please provide more information.

Comment: Calling tinymce editor in form 
var textArea_id = "work_scope";
tinymce.init({
 selector: "#work_scope"}):

Comment: Use the line you just posted in the success part of your ajax call.

When using jQuery:

.success(data) {
    $(".yourcontainer").append(data); // first append your form data
    var textArea_id = "work_scope"; tinymce.init({ selector: "#work_scope"}); // then initialize tinymce editor
}